# i wonder why i'm start flask with flask run but alway debugmode off

Tags: python, flask

i wonder why i'm start flask with flask run but alway debugmode off .
when i'm using python app.py debug mode on.
can explain me about run **python app.py** and **flask run** how different?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    @app.route("/")
    @app.route("/index")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False)
```

this image when i'm start with flask run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaoCE.png)

and this image i'm using python app.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmCbD.png)

Comment: Using `app.py` directly sets the program module name to [`__main__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), while using `flask run` does not do that so the `app.run` line in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block does not execute.